# Solving sudoku by recursion

Tags: java, recursion, sudoku

I tried writing recursion to solve sudoku, and I'm having a problem with the recursion.
If it's unsolvable its ok, but if it is solvable it is getting to infinite loop.

```
public static boolean recursion (int sodukuMatrix[][],int posRow, int posCol ,int i){

    if (posRow==0 && posCol==0 && i==10)
        return false;

    if(there is existing number){
        if (posCol==8 && posRow==8)
            return true;
        call recursion with next square
    }
    else {
        i=sodukuMatrix[posRow][posCol]+1;
        while (i<10){
            if (function: if I put i at the current location it is ok){
                sodukuMatrix[posRow][posCol]=i;        
                if (posCol==8 && posRow==8)
                    return true;
                call recursion with next square
            }
            else    
                i++;
        }
        sodukuMatrix[posRow][posCol]=0;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a version of this code that *compiles*.  Having that would make this easier to figure out.

Comment: i am still newbie at programming so i dont really know how to do it (or what exactly you mean..) . thanks

Comment: The code you've posted does *not* get into an infinite loop, because it is not valid java.  It doesn't compile, so you can't execute it at all.  There's are syntax errors at: `if(rec (cloneMatrix, sodukuMatrix, posRow, posCol+1 ,i)) }`, and, obviously, at `if (function: if I put i at the current location it is ok){`.

Answer (score 1):

To go a little down the rabbit hole. Solving Sudoko seems like an application of `Constraint-Satisfaction` in a context similar to the `N-Queens Problem` A `MIN-CONFLICTS` algorithm can be used in combination with `Simulated Annealing` to find the optimal solution.

Consider this pseudocode from [Peter Norvig's Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)

```
function MIN-CONFLICTS(csp, max_steps) returns a solution or failure
  inputs: csp, a constraint satisfaction problem
  max_steps, the number of steps allowed before giving up

  current <- an initial complete assignment for csp
  for I = 1 to max_steps do
    if current is a solution for csp then return current
    var <- a randomly chosen conflicted variable from csp.VARIABLES
    value <- the value v for var that minimizes CONFLICTS(var, v, current, csp)
    set var = value in current
  return failure
```

The CONFLICTS function counts the number of constraints violated by a particular value, given the rest of the current assignment.